# DevExpress TreeList Custom Button

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, xtratreelist

I have a DevExpress `ASPxTreeList` and I have some Custom Buttons in it.
Now, I need to perform  a server side action on custom Button Click.
Can anyone tell me,which `event` fires on `Custom Button Click`?

Comment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q266526